# strncpy question (C language)

Tags: c, string, strncpy

I'm having difficulty with strncpy. I'm trying to split a string of 8 characters in two (the first 6 characters in one substring and then the remaining 2 characters in another). To illustrate the particular difficulty I have simplified my code to the following:

```
include stdio.h
include stdlib.h
include string.h

define MAXSIZE 100

struct word {  
   char string[8];  
   char sub1[2];  
   char sub2[6];  
};

typedef struct word Word;

int main(void)  
{  
   Word* p;  
   p=(Word*)malloc(MAXSIZE*sizeof(Word));  
   if (p==NULL) {  
      fprintf(stderr,"not enough memory");  
      return 0;  
   }  
   printf("Enter an 8-character string: \n");  
   scanf("%s",p->string);  

   strncpy(p->sub2,p->string,6);  
   strncpy(p->sub1,p->string,2);  
   printf("string=%s\n",p->string);  
   printf("sub1=%s\n",p->sub1);  
   printf("sub2=%s\n",p->sub2);  

   free(p);  

   return 0;  
}
```

The user is prompted for an input. Suppose they input "12345678". Then the output of the program is:

```
string=1234567812123456  
sub1=12123456  
sub2=123456
```

The output I am expecting would be as follows:

```
string=12345678  
sub1=12  
sub2=123456
```

I don't understand how strncpy seems to be appending numbers to string... Obviously I don't understand strncpy well enough, but can anyone explain to me what's going on?

Comment: You want to certainly get rid of that malloc cast! http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Answer (score 6):

C strings need to be terminated with a null character (0).

[`strncpy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcpy#strncpy) does not put a null terminator on the string for you. If you want a 2-character string, you need to allocate room for three characters, and set the final one to null.

Try this:

```
struct word {
char string[9];
char sub1[3];
char sub2[7];
};

// ...
strncpy(p->sub2,p->string,6);
p->sub2[6] = 0;
strncpy(p->sub1,p->string,2);
p->sub1[2] = 0;
// ...
```

Note that if the user inputs more characters than you've allocated room for, you'll end up with problems.

Comment: thank you and thanks to the other posters. i understand now what was happening, and have been able to fix my code accordingly. very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

You may find this part of the [`strncpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) documentation useful:

> The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes  of  src
>       are  copied.  Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes
>       of src, the string placed in dest will not be null terminated.

You are printing strings that are not null-terminated. To fix this declare `sub1` and `sub2` with an extra char for the terminator:

```
char sub1[3];
char sub2[7];
```

And then null terminate after copying:

```
strncpy(p->sub2,p->string,6);  
p->sub2[6] = '\0';
strncpy(p->sub1,p->string,2); 
p->sub1[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: That's not sufficient. You should also place that null terminator there after you copy.

Comment: The strncpy() function always writes 'n' bytes to the destination, as does memcpy().  The only difference between strncpy() and memcpy() is that bytes following the first zero byte will be written as zero, rather than being copied from the source.

Answer (score 1):

> The strncpy() function copies at most
>   n characters from s2 into s1.  If
>   s2 is less than n characters long, the remainder of s1 is filled
>   with `\0' characters.  Otherwise, s1 is not terminated.

So given your string is longer, the strings are not zero terminated. When you print them, prinf is printing the characters you copied, but then carrying on printing whatever is there until it hits a NUL

Althoug scanf does NUL terminate its string, you've not allocated enough space. `String` in your stuct needs to be *9* characters long - 8 for the characters (12345678) and one more for the NUL. Right now the NUL is going in the first character of str1 - which you then overwrite with the strncpy

Comment: _remainder of s1_ always remains unchanged in my experience (MinGW). Maybe is _filled with \0 characters_ in other environments.

Comment: @Salvador, that's a bug in MinGW then. With a quick web search I cannot a reference to it.