# Substring replacement and memcpy

Tags: c, string

Based on suggestions in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44687473/locating-and-replacing-a-substring-c-language/44687849#44687849), I've written the following program that finds, and replaces, a target substring in a string. (It could be run in a loop to find and replace all instances of "target" using the `strstr()` string method, but I just give an example here.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SUCCESS 1
#define FAILURE 0
#define STR_CAP 80 + 1

int stringify(char *string, const char *target, const char *replacement) {
    char segment[STR_CAP];
    int S = strlen(string), T = strlen(target);
    char pre_segment[STR_CAP];
    char post_segment[STR_CAP];

    for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
        strncpy(segment, string + i, T);
        segment[T] = '\0';
        if (strcmp(segment, target) == 0) {
            memcpy(pre_segment, string, i);
            /*printf("pre_segment: %s\n", pre_segment);*/
            pre_segment[i] = '\0';
            memcpy(post_segment, string + i + T, S - (i + T));
            post_segment[S - (i + T)] = '\0'; /*WHAT IS THIS MAGIC?*/
            /*printf("post_segment: %s\n", post_segment);*/     
            strcat(pre_segment, replacement);
            /*printf("pre_segment after concat.: %s\n", pre_segment);*/
            strcat(pre_segment, post_segment);
            /*printf("pre_segment after concat,: %s\n", pre_segment);*/
            strcpy(string, pre_segment);
            return SUCCESS;
        }   
    } return FAILURE;
}

int main() {

    char string[] = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy, brown dog.";
    char target[] = "brown";
    char replacement[] = "ochre-ish";

    stringify(string, target, replacement);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    stringify(string, target, replacement);
    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0;

}
```

But there are some things I don't understand.

(1) For one thing: before I used `memcpy()` and manually set the ends of the strings I copied to `'\0'`, I kept getting buffer-overflows (in the form of stack-smashing), and weird errors. What effect does this have that just naively using `strncpy()` doesn't? For example, if you comment out the "MAGIC" line, the program just about implodes.

(2) Is there a nicer or more canonical way of doing this? This feels very clunky, but I couldn't find any basic "how-tos" on substring replacement.

Comment: To be clear - you want to replace a 'target' sub-string with a 'replacement' sub-string that is longer than the target, in-place, without allocating a new string for the output?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit In this instance, yes - the background to this question is a program where invalid situations like that get caught and handled external to the operation of this function.

Comment: Well, since it's undefined behaviour, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @ThingWotsit Not sure what you mean. If "replacement' is too long to be put into "string" without overflowing the 80 non-null characters allowed, the other part of this program will check for that, see that, and refuse to call "stringify".

Comment: @Chris You again forgot to append the copied string with a zero character at least in thisstatement strncpy(segment, string + i, T); as I already pointed in your previous question.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow oh no. segment[T] = '\0', right?

Comment: @Chris It is better now.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow So thank you once again for pointing that out! I'm still not sure I 100% get what situations you need to manually add '\0' in, but it seems like copying strings is one of them?

Comment: @Chris When the function strncpy is used instead of strcpy then it can copy a substring of the source string without the terminating zero. In this case the result array will not contain a string.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ahhh. Ok, that makes sense.

Comment: **Please stop using `strncpy`!** It is never the right tool in the hands of a beginner and still too error prone for more experienced C programmers. Learn about this here: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Answer (score 2):

1. `memcpy()` only copies memory and has no recollection of strings and null terminators. `strncpy()` will copy the first n characters and will fill the rest with 0s (null terminator) only if the null terminator was found in the n characters, so chances were you gave `strncpy()` the length of the strings you wanted to copy, which it did, but did not find a null terminator. In this sense, `strncpy()` acted just like `memcpy()`. Either way, you needed to manually assign the null terminator. 
   The memory is being corrupted simply because the program reads a string, but does not find a null terminator, and therefore will continue to read, until it goes past the stack, the heap, and the rest of the memory until it reaches a null terminator (not in that order).
2. There are a lot of ways to do substring replacement, here is another way to do it that is slightly more elegant: [What is the function to replace string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c)

EDIT in response to: "Can you explain more about what memcpy() does and why people are so unhappy with strncpy()?"

Imagine your memory looks like this:

```
0              3    
01 | 30 | 40 | 00 | 32 | 40
```

I then execute `memcpy(0x03, 0x00, 3);` telling the computer to copy 3 bytes from address 0 to address 3. Now my memory looks like this:

```
0              3    
01 | 30 | 40 | 01 | 30 | 40
```

The computer quite literally copies over as I instructed, byte by byte. Lets take a look at what `strncpy()` would do in this scenario. Starting from the first diagram above, calling `strncpy(0x03, 0x00, 3);` telling the computer to copy the null-terminated char array (string) at 0x00, to 0x03, but maxing out at 3 characters. The result is:

```
0              3    
01 | 30 | 40 | 01 | 30 | 40
```

Lets imagine instead that we started out with:

```
0              3    
65 | 00 | 40 | 01 | 30 | 40
```

Here, address 0x00 actually refers to a 1 character long string: "A".
Now, if we call the same `strncpy(0x03, 0x00, 3)` the computer first copies over the 65, notices a null terminator, and stops there. Then it fills the remaining parts with 0, with this result:

```
0              3    
65 | 00 | 40 | 65 | 00 | 00
```

You can see that if your string is longer than 3 characters, the `strncpy` would not copy over a null terminator for you, since it will "max out". This is the same as `memcpy`. `strncpy` will only move a null terminator over to the destination if it encounters a null terminator in the first n bytes. Therefore, you can see in the first few examples, even though address 0x00 contained a 3 character valid string (terminating with 0 at address 0x03), the `strncpy()` function did not produce a valid string at the destination (0x03), since 0x04 could be anything (not necessarily a null terminator).

Comment: So in this instance there wasn't a meaningful difference between strncpy() and memcpy(). Can you explain more about what memcpy() does and why people are so unhappy with strncpy()?

Comment: `strncpy`: just say no: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Comment: @Chris-- because `strcpy()` always copies the `\0` (if there is room, and UB if not), the result is always a string. But, as you have found, `strncpy()` does _not_ always copy the `\0`, and does not add one; yet people often mistakenly believe that it is like other `strX()` functions that result in strings. This source of confusion is removed when using `memcpy()` and `memmove()`, since there is no false expectation of automagically generating strings.

Comment: @Chris-- I should have added that `strncpy()` _will_ add `\0` characters if `n` is larger than the size of the source string. The complexity in the behavior of `strncpy()` makes the simplicity of using `memcpy()` and `memmove()` appealing.

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy()` just copies a number of bytes from an array to another one.  It is a very simple function with 2 caveats:

- it should not be used when the source and destination arrays overlap.
- it is meant to copy bytes, so the size must be computed as a number of bytes, which is error prone when copying between arrays of largers types.  In this case, the `char` type is by definition exactly one byte, so the size is just the number of characters, plus 1 for the null terminator if needed.

`memmove()` does the same as `memcpy`, but it can be used for overlapping objects.  It needs an extra test to handle all cases correctly.

Using these functions, here is a much simpler version of your `stringify` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int stringify(char *dest, const char *target, const char *replace) {
    char *p = strstr(dest, target);
    if (p == NULL) {
        /* no replacement */
        return 0;
    }
    size_t len1 = strlen(target);
    size_t len2 = strlen(replace);
    if (len1 != len2) {
        /* move the remainder of the string into the right place */
        memmove(p + len2, p + len1, strlen(p + len1) + 1);
    }
    memcpy(p, replace, len2);
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    char string[80] = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy, brown dog.";
    char target[] = "brown";
    char replacement[] = "ochre-ish";

    stringify(string, target, replacement);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    stringify(string, target, replacement);
    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- this function does not check if the destination array has enough space when the replacement is longer than the target string.
- In your code, the destination string is not long enough, producing a buffer overflow causing undefined behavior.
- `memmove` must be used instead of `memcpy` to shift the remainder of the string because the source and destination arrays overlap.
- calling `stringify` iteratively may not produce the expected replacements if the target and replacement strings have a common part: replacing `brown` with `brownish` will obviously fail for multiple matches.

Replacing all matches in a loop, and allocating the resulting string is not difficult:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *replace_all(const char *str, const char *target, const char *replace) {
    size_t len1 = strlen(target);
    size_t len2 = strlen(replace);
    size_t matches = 0;
    const char *p, *p0;
    char *dest, *q;

    if (len1 > 0) {
        for (p = str; p = strstr(p, target) != NULL; p += len1)
            matches++;
    }
    if (matches == 0) {
        return strdup(str);
    }
    dest = malloc(strlen(str) - len1 * matches + len2 * matches + 1);
    if (dest != NULL) {
        for (p = str, q = dest; (p = strstr(p0 = p, target)) != NULL; p += len1) {
            memcpy(q, p0, p - p0);
            q += p - p0;
            memcpy(q, replace, len2);
            q += len2;
        }
        memcpy(q, p0, strlen(p0) + 1);
    }
    return dest;       
}

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy, brown dog.";
    char target[] = "brown";
    char replacement[] = "brownish";

    char *p = replace_all(string, target, replacement);
    printf("%s\n", p);
    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a big problem with your approach: `replacement` can be long enough
that the result string would be longer than 80 characters long.

I'd do it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *stringify(const char *src, const char *target, const char *replacement)
{
    int buffer_len = 0;
    char *buffer = NULL, *tmp;
    if(src == NULL || replacement == NULL || target == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int repl_len = strlen(replacement);
    int target_len = strlen(target);

    while(tmp = strstr(src, target) && target_len)
    {
        // get length of string until target
        int substr_len = tmp - src;

        // get more space
        char *new_buff = realloc(buffer, buffer_len + substr_len + repl_len + 1);

        if(new_buff == NULL)
        {
            // out of memory
            return buffer;
        }

        if(buffer == NULL) // first realloc
            *new_buff = 0;

        buffer = new_buff;

        // copy that what is before the found target
        strncat(buffer, src, substr_len);

        buffer[buffer_len + substr_len] = 0;

        //// copy the replacement at the end of buffer
        strncat(buffer, replacement, repl_len);

        buffer[buffer_len + substr_len + repl_len] = 0;

        buffer_len += substr_len + repl_len;

        //// set src to the next character after the replacement
        src = tmp + target_len;
    }

    if(buffer == NULL) // target never found
    {
        buffer = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);
        if(buffer == NULL)
            return NULL;

        strcpy(buffer, src);
    } else {
        if(*src) {
            // copy the leftover
            int leftover_len = strlen(src);

            char *new_buff = realloc(buffer, buffer_len + leftover_len + 1);

            if(new_buff == NULL)
                return buffer; // could not expand more, return all we've converted

            buffer = new_buff;

            strcat(buffer, src);
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}


int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy, brown dog.";
    char target[] = "brown";
    char replacement[] = "ochre-ish";

    char *new_txt = stringify(string, target, replacement);

    if(new_txt)
    {
        printf("new string: %s\n", new_txt);
        free(new_txt);
    } else
        printf("Out of memory\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Of course you could improve the code but my code should show how to use
`realloc` and pointer arithmetic which is very important when you start
manipulating string or array of data.

Comment: you call `strncat` with an uninitialized destination array `buffer`.  Why not use `memcpy`?

Comment: you should also test that `target` is not empty, otherwise the `while` loop will run forever.

Comment: @chqrlie thanks, I forgot that only `calloc` initializes the memory with 0. With target being blank, I didn't thought about that. I've updated the code.